# JSON.NET deserialization of List<TypeX> property named TypeX

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We are currently implementing a JSON based communication protocol (so we can't change the data contract names/types) and ran into a problem deserializing a class containing a property: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '...PriceScheme' ...'

```
public class RootElement {
   public List<PriceScheme> PriceScheme { get; set; }
}

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootElement>(json);
```

Personally I would name the damn thing PriceSchemes (and the deserialization works fine if you do), but as I mentioned I can't in order to be compatible. We are using the same data contract class (from a shared DLL) on both the server and client and also serialize it using JSON.NET.

My guess is that JSON.NET tries to deserialize the List directly as PriceScheme because of the matching name. Is there a way to configure/disable this behavior?

Example JSON:

```
{
    "PriceScheme": [{
        "PriceSchemeId": 1,
        "DisplayText": null,
        "Connector": 0,
        "ExpiryDate": null,
        "Tariff": [{
            "TariffId": 1,
            "DisplayText": {
                "Language": null,
                "Text": "DefaulttesttariffforoffpeakusingkWh."
            },
            "PricingUnit": 2,
            "Currency": {
                "StrCurrency": "EUR"
            },
            "PriceTaxed": 0.12,
            "PriceUntaxed": 0.1,
            "TaxPct": 0.2,
            "Condition": "OffPeak"
        },
        {
            "TariffId": 2,
            "DisplayText": {
                "Language": null,
                "Text": "DefaulttesttariffforoffpeakusingkWh."
            },
            "PricingUnit": 1,
            "Currency": {
                "StrCurrency": "EUR"
            },
            "PriceTaxed": 36.0,
            "PriceUntaxed": 0.0,
            "TaxPct": 0.0,
            "Condition": "OffPeak"
        }],
        "LocalCalculationAllowed": true
    }]
}
```

The root element class is called SetPricingReq:

```
public class SetPricingReq
    {
        public SetPricingReq(PriceScheme priceScheme)
        {
            this.PriceScheme = new List<PriceScheme> { priceScheme };
        }

        [Required]
        public List<PriceScheme> PriceScheme { get; set; }
    }
```

The next one in (and it already fails there so I'll skip the rest) is the PriceScheme:

```
public class PriceScheme
    {
        public PriceScheme(int priceSchemeId, Tariff tariff, bool localCalculationAllowed)
        {
            this.PriceSchemeId = priceSchemeId;
            this.Tariff = new List<Tariff> { tariff };
            this.LocalCalculationAllowed = localCalculationAllowed;
        }
        [Required]
        public int PriceSchemeId { get; set; }

        public LocalizedText DisplayText { get; set; }

        public ConnectorType Connector { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public List<Tariff> Tariff { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool LocalCalculationAllowed { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post an example json and example class structure? It seems to work fine for me, just tried it with your specific example and I got multiple PriceScheme objects deserialized into that list.

Comment: Could you also try with just a single one (happens to be the case for me at the moment ... field is defined 1..*)...

Comment: Also posted example JSON and classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the deserialization failed because the data classes did not implement a default constructor (the protocol we are implementing requires certain fields to be not null, so we made sure they couldn't be). So we will either have to add public default constructors or find a way to get the custom converter solution going to create the objects using their non-default constructors.

Update: To be more exact, the non-default constructor was used by JSON.net but since the property has the logical definition of 1...* we added only a single PriceScheme not List to the constructor of the class. JSON.net was then mapping the paramater name to the property, found a match and then complained that the types aren't compatible which was correct since it got a collection from the JSON but no way of passing that in.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic helps this scenario

you would probably not need class RootElement and you do as:

```
dynamic root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom contract resolver to explicitly define how to deserialize a certain field:

```
public class ConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        foreach(var property in properties.Where(p => p.PropertyName == "MyProperty"))
            property.Converter = new CustomConverter();

        return properties;
    }
}


public abstract class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t)
    {
        return typeof(MyType).IsAssignableFrom(t);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new MyType();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```